# Intel IOTT Open Source Reference Implementations: Create a Restricted Zone Notification Solution

Tags: intel, intel-nuc

I am using an Intel Upsquare board running Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to run Intel IOTT Open Source Reference Implementations, https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/reference-implementations/restricted-zone-notifier. I follow all the steps on the github download and instruction file and try to execute one of the sample files they have provided. However, I am unable to execute the problem due to a problem with the ./monitor area. I am getting an error message saying

> ./monitor: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libinference_engine.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   directory.

I am unable to debug the cause for these issues.

Comment: Read `man ld.so` and `man ldconfig`